# PHP use variable inside function

Tags: php, function, scope

This is really simple but I can't get my head around it.  I am setting a datestamp and would like to be able to use it inside a function like this..

```
    $date_stamp = date("dmy",time());

    function myfunction() {
        echo $date_stamp;
    }
```

This is not working and $date_stamp is not available inside the function, how can I use this?

Comment: @RyanVincent OMG, you are correct! deleted that nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic PHP. `$date_stamp` is out of scope within your function. To be in scope you must pass it as a parameter:

```
$date_stamp = date("dmy",time());

function myfunction($date) {
    echo $date;
}

// call function
myfunction($date_stamp);
```

See [PHP variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: of course you can also move `$date_stamp = date("dmy",time());` in side the function.

Comment: Very true. I don't know if this was a MCRE or not so I left it i as is.

Comment: You can also use `global` but making such a suggestion around here wouldn't be well received

Comment: @amenadiel Someone did and then deleted it due to comments they received about it :)

Comment: It was a valid answer tho. You could even hard code the current date if you care enough to do it daily

Answer (score 1):

Just as an add-on to John Conde's answer, you can also use a closure like so

```
<?php
$date_stamp = date("dmy",time());

$myfunction = function() use ($date_stamp)  {
    echo '$myfunction: date is '. $date_stamp;
};

$myfunction();
```